# Process “ubd” high CPU usage

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

I noticed my MBP got really slow, which must be strange with SSD and 8GB of RAM.

So I opened the Activity Monitor to discover a process called `ubd` keeps its CPU usage very high, about 120% most of the time:

[image: ubd process]

I found a thread that [discusses the issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3396579?start=0&tstart=0) but it is related to having hundreds of iCloud certificates in the keychain, which I don't.

[image: Just a few iCloud certificates]

How do I go on with diagnosing the issue?

Comment: Could you specify which version of 10.7 you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By observing log messages in `~/Library/Logs/Ubiquity/<my username>/`, I realized that Ubiquity (iCloud process) kept trying to create a file in a folder that doesn't exist:

[image: ubiquity log]

I opened up the Terminal and created this directory and its parent directories up to `.ubd`:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/
sudo mkdir .ubd && cd .ubd
sudo mkdir peer-E2B13E4F-56F7-C79B-1621-E30738B638FE-v23 && cd peer-E2B13E4F-56F7-C79B-1621-E30738B638FE-v23
sudo mkdir ftr
```

Then I changed the newly created directories' owner from root to myself:

```
cd ../..
sudo chown -R <my username> .ubd/
```

The fan turned silent instantly.

Comment: Nice catch. I'll add that, if I'm not mistaken, you can use `mkdir` with the `-p` switch to create parent directories as needed on a specified path, rather than combining multiple `mkdir` and `cd` commands. :)

Comment: `sudo` probably isn't required here

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5208590?start=0&tstart=0 :

"Applications that can store documents in iCloud include Preview, TextEdit, Pages, Numbers, Keynote, GarageBand, and some third-party software such as "DayOne," "iA Writer," "MindNode," and perhaps others. If some or all of those applications are suddenly not working well, there may be a problem with iCloud synchronization.

**Back up all data.**

Open the iCloud preference pane in System Preferences and uncheck the box marked **Documents & Data**. See whether there's any improvement. If there is, continue.

Hold down the option key and select

**Go ▹ Library**

from the Finder menu bar. From the folder that opens, move this folder to the Desktop:
Mobile Documents (or any other item with a name beginning that way)
and move this folder to the Trash:
Application Support/Ubiquity
Re-enable **Documents & Data**, log out, log back in, and test. The folders should be recreated automatically. If the issue is resolved, delete the folder you moved to the Desktop.

If you continue to have the same problems, I suggest you contact iCloud Support."

-Linc Davis