# softwaredownloadd consuming insane amounts of RAM

Tags: macos, mojave, memory, performance

When I went into Activity Monitor, I noticed that a process called `storedownloadd` was consuming 2.7GB of RAM and increasing RAM usage steadily (3.1GB during screenshot). However, it was not consuming any CPU cycles, and I am not downloading or updating anything. Why is it consuming so much RAM without using any or very little CPU cycles?

I also noticed that my compressed memory was 3GB. Is this linked to the process' RAM?

[image: Storedownloadd's RAM usage]
[image: Total RAM Usage]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106697/insanely-high-kernel-ram-usage-over-9gb-in-mavericks?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49715/process-ubd-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do downloads (storedownloadd) from the Mac App Store consume so much CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226121/why-do-downloads-storedownloadd-from-the-mac-app-store-consume-so-much-cpu)

Comment: @ankii I am not downloading anything and there is no usage of the CPU

Comment: storedownloadd is currently consuming 14.42 GB of memory on my MacBook Pro (Mojave v10.14.6). This is crazy! I hope a reboot will help.

Comment: Yes, a reboot helped. Let's see for how long though...

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of the high CPU topic. This is RAM usage. I'm running into the same issue now. Just force quiting softwaredownloadd returned the RAM to me, but I would be interested to know WHY that happened